# Django ImportError: cannot import name ForumProfile

Tags: django, importerror, django-1.7

I use virtualenv for django.

And run   python manage.py runserver  at cmd.

> In this site, the questions like importError most of them didn't be
>   solved.
>
> with my question, some day it can be sovled in the end. >_<

```html
(virtual_env_django_1.7)cundi@cundideAir ~/P/Forum> python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/cundi/virtual_env_django_1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/cundi/virtual_env_django_1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/cundi/virtual_env_django_1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/cundi/virtual_env_django_1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/cundi/virtual_env_django_1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 197, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/cundi/PycharmProjects/Forum/accounts/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from my_forum.models import Topic, Post
  File "/Users/cundi/PycharmProjects/Forum/my_forum/models.py", line 9, in <module>
    from utils.bbs_utils import get_delta_time
  File "/Users/cundi/PycharmProjects/Forum/utils/bbs_utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    from utils import conf
  File "/Users/cundi/PycharmProjects/Forum/utils/conf.py", line 4, in <module>
    from accounts.models import ForumProfile
ImportError: cannot import name ForumProfile
```

Using google searched similar Error.But has not solve it.

This is my accounts.models.py files.

may be there is a problem.

```html
class BaseSiteUser(models.Model):
    # you can get user info like this: user.base_site_user_set.all()[0]
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)


class Profile(BaseSiteUser):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    user_avatar = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    avatar_img = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='avatar', default='avatar/d_avatar.png')
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, blank=True)
    born_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name=u'出生日期', null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    date_created = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=u'账户创建日期', auto_now_add=True)


class ForumProfile(Profile):
    favorite = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, verbose_name='fav_user', related_name='fav', blank=True)
    vote = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, verbose_name='vote_user', related_name='vote', blank=True)
    coins = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    last_activity = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_posttime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    signature = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='This guy is lazy that nothing to leave')
    website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

This is model.py file's some snippet. Hope it will help.

Does has something wrong with settings.py ?

```html
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SECRET_KEY = '1-ygln+^^7=5=c)u3#2ozm#jiu)6=65m((rg09pwl069242@vc'

DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'accounts',
    'my_forum',
    'utils',
    'blog',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Forum.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Forum.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_files'),)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/public'),

    )

MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = "524288"

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER

LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),)
```

Comment: What does your `accounts.models` look like ?

Comment: May has wrong with setting.py ?

Comment: Does your folder contains __init__.py? Also, your file is named 'models.py' right? Not 'model.py' as you wrote?

Comment: absolutely yes.        ── Forum
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── accounts
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc ..........

Comment: Oops. I got a typo. It should be models.py.  But , the problem of  Import Error still in there.

Comment: You appear to have a circular import (see the last 8 lines or so from your traceback); perhaps that's a problem.